# Can I push object inside of forEach() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm just learning js, and have some question that doable on php, but doesn't work the same way on js. I need to take an array, loop it and push value from each of this array to my different data array. It's piece of my Vue

```
shares() {
            this.preferredEquities.forEach(function(element) {

            // what is the right way to do it?
              this.shares_amount.push(element.capital_committed)

            });
        },
```

Comment: The value of `this` isn't going to be what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks man, Problem solved!